# Most reliable way to identify the current user through a sudo

Tags: linux, process, sudo

I have an application that may or may not be run while users are sudo'ed to a shared user account.  I would like to reliably identify who the real user is for a sort of "honor-system" ACL.  I think there's some way by tracing parent/group/session process ids the way that the `pstree` command does, but I'm not sure how to do that best or if there are better alternatives.

I tried `getlogin()` originally.  That works if `./myapp` is used, but it fails with 'cat input | ./myapp` (because the "controlling terminal" is a pipe owned by the shared account).

I'd rather not trust environment variables, as I don't want my "honor system" to be completely thwarted by a simply `unset`, when the information is still available elsewhere.

I'd also like to avoid forcing a lookup in the password database, as that is a remote RPC (NIS or LDAP) and I'm pretty sure `wtmp` already contains the information I need.

Answer (score 2):

For a shell script, you might use this to get the sudo'ing user:

```
WHO=$(who am i | sed -e 's/ .*//'`)
```

and extract the id from the login using:

```
ID_WHO=$(id -u $WHO)
```

I'll ferret out the C library equivalent later.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` sets the environment variables `SUDO_USER`, `SUDO_UID`, and `SUDO_GID`.

You can test this with:

```
$ sudo env
[sudo] password for shteef: 
TERM=xterm
# [...snip...]
SHELL=/bin/bash
LOGNAME=root
USER=root
USERNAME=root
SUDO_COMMAND=/usr/bin/env
SUDO_USER=shteef
SUDO_UID=1000
SUDO_GID=1000
```

But if your users have shell access on the shared account, then I suppose you cannot blindly trust this either.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
username=`id | cut -d"=" -f2 | cut -d" " -f1`

if [ $username == "0(root)" ]
then
  print "Yes, the user is root"
else
 print "Sorry! the user $username, is not a root"
fi
```